# jquery simple set attribute to element and TypeError: $(...).atrr is not a function

Tags: jquery, find, attr

I got this code

```
<div class="separator">
    <a href="{img src}">
        <img src="{img src}" style="width:100%" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Now i need  to < a > element set attribute with "postimg" value after DOM i loaded. So i trying do this with code below:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('div.separator a').atrr("data-attribute","postimg");

        });
    </script>
```

Unfortunely in console error appear

```
TypeError: $(...).atrr is not a function
```

also trying with this code i get this error

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('div.separator')find.("a").atrr("data-attribute","postimg");

        });
    </script>
```

I don't understand, what i do wrong? Please help

Comment: Try `attr()` instead of `atrr()`. For reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ . And btw it's not `$('div.separator')find.("a")` but `$('div.separator').find("a")`

Comment: Oh my God! Im so blind, im so damn blind. Thank You very much! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error message because of a typo - it's `attr()` instead of `atrr()`. For reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/.

In addition, in the second version of your code it should be

```
$('div.separator').find("a")
```

instead of

```
$('div.separator')find.("a")
```

**Note:** I already posted this answer as comment but thought it'd be better to add it also as an answer so the question won't appear when users are looking for unanswered questions.